# Does GA proviides a standard api specification to automatically generate a client

Tags: google-analytics

Do you know if GA is providing a standard (json/swagger/xml) file 
that describes their API to generate client api ?

I can t find it looking into service discovery and other online places.

I need it to generate a client for a language not yet supported by ga

Answer (score 0):

Why yes of course, that would be the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/), which is language agnostic and can be implemented in any language that can issue http requests.

This is simply an endpoint with a number of mandatory (tracking id, client id etc) and optional parameters. Just assemble your tracking url and fire it off.

Comment: hi thanks, yes, i updated my question to precise i m looking for an easy to interpret document. The one provided is related, but the format is not friendly. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters